# why is this html and css rendering differently on my webpage?

Tags: html, css

I really liked the toggle switch "Example 3" on this website and they provide the HTML/CSS code with it. Although, when I try it on my webpage it renders as a simple plain checkbox.
I have beginners knowledge of HTML/CSS but the code makes sense and I'm not sure what is wrong.

This is the code and the website attached on the bottom. Example 3 is what it's supposed to look like.

```css
<style>
/* Switch Yes No
==========================*/
.switch-yes-no {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-image: none;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label {
    box-shadow: none;
    background: none;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:after, .switch-yes-no .switch-label:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:after {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #32CD32;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:before {
    background: #eceeef;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-handle {
    display: none;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
    background: #FFF;
    border-color: #0088cc;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
    transform: rotateY(180deg)
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
    transform: rotateY(0)
}
</style>
```

```html
<label class="switch switch-yes-no">
    <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
    <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> 
    <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
</label>
```

Example 3 on this website in case needed
[Example 3](https://www.htmllion.com/css3-toggle-switch-button.html)

Comment: You need to also include the styling from below “The Common CSS” at the start of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the instruction carefully. On the top of the page you have a part `The Common CSS`. This style must be used for all examples below.

For example 3 you need to add the part you have used.

```css
.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
    border-radius: 18px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: inherit;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #eceeef;
    border-radius: inherit;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label:before, .switch-label:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -.5em;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-transition: inherit;
    -moz-transition: inherit;
    -o-transition: inherit;
    transition: inherit;
    box-sizing:content-box;
}
.switch-label:before {
    content: attr(data-off);
    right: 11px;
    color: #aaaaaa;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.switch-label:after {
    content: attr(data-on);
    left: 11px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
    background: #E1B42B;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
    opacity: 0;
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.switch-handle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
    border-radius: 100%;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.switch-handle:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}
.switch-input:checked ~ .switch-handle {
    left: 74px;
    box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
 
/* Transition
========================== */
.switch-label, .switch-handle {
    transition: All 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}

.switch-yes-no {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    background: #FFF;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-image: none;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label {
    box-shadow: none;
    background: none;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:after, .switch-yes-no .switch-label:before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:after {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background: #32CD32;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-label:before {
    background: #eceeef;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-handle {
    display: none;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label {
    background: #FFF;
    border-color: #0088cc;
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:before {
    transform: rotateY(180deg)
}
.switch-yes-no .switch-input:checked ~ .switch-label:after {
    transform: rotateY(0)
}
```

```html
<label class="switch switch-yes-no">
    <input class="switch-input" type="checkbox" />
    <span class="switch-label" data-on="Yes" data-off="No"></span> 
    <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as the other answers suggest.. You need to add proper styling i.e., all the style classes or files needed. Also, I would like to add that include these files in their proper order inside your project. Remember, order is very important.